# Undefined variable: dataProvider in yii2 kartik grid

Tags: php, yii-extensions, kartik-v

I'm trying to learn about **kartik grid view** and I'm having trouble with dataProvider.

**Controller Code**

this is the full controller code (not all though, i just show the code until code containing the dataProvider that i asked why it's undefined)

```
class SiteController extends Controller {
 public function actions()
 {
return [
    'error' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\ErrorAction',
    ],
    'captcha' => [
        'class' => 'yii\captcha\CaptchaAction',
        'fixedVerifyCode' => YII_ENV_TEST ? 'testme' : null,
    ],
];
}


public function actionIndex()
{
if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
if (Yii::$app->user->identity->akses === '1'){
    return $this->render('knpr/knpr-home');
} else if (Yii::$app->user->identity->akses === '2') {
    return $this->render('prov/prov-home');
} else if (Yii::$app->user->identity->akses === '3') {
    return $this->render('kabkot/kabkot-home');
} else if (Yii::$app->user->identity->akses === '4') {
    return $this->render('multiregional/multiregional-home');
}
  }
//return $this->render('home-knpr');
}


public function actionLogin()
{   $this->layout = 'main-login';
if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
    return $this->goHome();
   }

  $model = new LoginForm();
  if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->login()) {
    return $this->goBack();
   }
return $this->render('login', [
    'model' => $model,
]);
  }

public function actionLogout()
{
Yii::$app->user->logout();
return $this->redirect(['site/login'])->send();
 }

public function actionKnprHome()
 {
    $totalCount = Yii::$app->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM m_admin') -> queryScalar();

$dataProvider = new SqlDataProvider([
    'db'  => Yii::$app->db,
    'sql' => 'SELECT * FROM m_admin',
    'totalCount' => $totalCount,
    'sort' => false,
    'pagination' => [
        'pageSize' => $count,
    ],
]);

return $this->render('knpr/knpr-home', array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider));

  }
```

**View Code**

```
<?php echo GridView::widget([ 
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'showOnEmpty' => true,
'emptyCell' => true,
'column' => [
    'username',
    'password',
    'akses',
    'kode_daerah',
    'authKey',
    'id',
    ],
'pjax' => true,
]);   ?>
```

and the output is :

> Undefined variable: dataProvider

error : 
[undefined var : dataProvider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Sk9i.png)

[more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RoSCi.png)

[more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9Zsc.png)

[more](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9b5Y.png)

Please suggest.

Comment: Please specify what kind of error/trouble you're having with kartik grid view.

Comment: it keeps telling that the data provider is undefined

Comment: by looking at your code its not possible to suggest anything, your code looks fine , please provide more details , may be more code from controller and view file and line no at which you are getting error

Comment: Why in your `render` line you specify the controller name? it should be only the view file name.

Comment: where? its view file name and directory

Comment: what is your action url?

Comment: i... don't know, view will be showed up when it hit this = if (Yii::$app->user->identity->akses === '1'){
    return $this->render('knpr/knpr-home');

Comment: but i don't know how to call the action 'public function actionKnprHome()' to be rendered

Comment: Use redirect: `return $this->redirect('site/knpr-home');`

Comment: where should i put it? it still doesn't work

Comment: Instead of this line: `return $this->render('knpr/knpr-home');`

Comment: still doesn't work

Comment: Still the same error? can you edit your post with full error trace?

Comment: still the same, i will show you the screenshot

Comment: It's seems you didn't change the right line: `SiteController` line 65 change to: `return $this->redirect(['site/knpr-home']);`

Comment: oh sorry, i put in the wrong line, i will report if any error showed up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, i changed line 65 into return $this->redirect(['site/knpr-home']);

and deleted all of the column variable in view site

```
<div>
<?php echo GridView::widget([ 
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'showOnEmpty' => true,
'emptyCell' => true,

'pjax' => true,
]); ?> </div>
```